# how do I load a single page in a sub theme?

Tags: theming, 7, social-network

I am creating a page in a Drupal website of mine so that I can use it for a custom iframe in a Facebook app. The reason for this is that Facebook uses 520 instead of 960, and I was wondering if there is a way to create a separate sub theme that would be used for a single page on my Drupal site.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [ThemeKey module](http://drupal.org/project/themekey).  From the project page:

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching
>   rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current
>   path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other
>   properties.

Answer (score 1):

Why an entire new theme? You can have body classes or page templates based on node id or content type. I would use the nid to have a different page template with different markup or you can have something like:

```
.node-56 #container{width:520px}
```

or

```
.node-type #container{width:520px}
```

Look at: http://drupal.org/node/1089656 for template suggestions

Answer (score 0):

There is a global variable $custom_theme. Set it in a module or template.php:

```
function masqtheme_init() {
  // url is facebook url, or referrer ... 
  // if (strpos($_GET['q'], 'facebook') !== 0)
   global $custom_theme;
   $custom_theme = 'mycouncil';
  }
}
```

[drupal api theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/theme/7)

This works in drupal-6 and drupal-7. In drupal-7 if playing with global variables has bad side-effects or feels dirty use:

```
hook_custom_theme()
```

instead. This returns the name of the theme for a specific page call. Mobile sites without mobileswitch are another case where we have used this.

Printing facebook canvas is a similar problem to displaying in a modal or print version of the site. The same result can be achieved by using a specific template e.g. page--facebook--news.tpl.php. Implement hook_theme() and hook_node_view(). You copy the existing page.tpl.php and remove the 'furniture' that you don't want.